# CREATE TABLE doesn't load data from disk

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveddl

I have a bunch of parquet files and I'm trying to load them into hive with the following query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `events` (
    // ... fields ...
)
PARTITIONED BY (... partition columns ...)
SORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/path/to/parquet/files';
```

It creates the table, but it doesn't load the data at the location. Is there something wrong with the query?

Comment: you have to `load data ..` after creating the table

Answer (score 0):

The location you specified in `CREATE TABLE` statement should be HDFS location. `CREATE TABLE` does not load files.

Use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH './local/file/path' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE invites PARTITION (key='value');` See manual [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted).

Alternatively, you can put files in the HDFS into locations with partitions subdirectories using `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /path/in/linux /hdfs/path` command, then create table and use `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` to create partitions, see manual [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)).